# No Audio Input using the Intel FPGA DE1-SOC board and the WM8731 Audio Codec

Tags: audio, intel, fpga

I am working on writing verilog code that initializes and creates a loop back of a mic auido to an output. I am using the Intel FPGA DE1-SOC board which has the WM8731 as the audio codec.

I have verified that the I2C configuraiton works becuase I am able to get the codec to acknoledge the configuration messages when I see the data on my logic analyizer on pulse view. See below for the logic output:

[image]

The orange line is where I turn on my program which first starts with a configuration of the registers of the codec and then it is waiting for audio to come in to loop back in the output line.

I have ensured that the mic in and line out ports are correctly hooked up to the board as shown below:

[image]

Since there is nothing in the adcdat section I thought I had not enabled the mic input correctly but I have check this and I think I have programmed the registers correctly as the following :

```
set_lin_l       : LUT_data <= 16'h001f; //Reg 0 Left Line in 
set_lin_r       : LUT_data <= 16'h021f; //Reg 1 Right Line in 


set_head_l      : LUT_data <= 16'h047f; //Reg 2 Left Heaphone Out 
set_head_r      : LUT_data <= 16'h067f; //Reg 3 Right Headphone Out 

a_path_cntrl    : LUT_data <= 16'h0805; //Reg 4 Analogue Audio Path Conttrol 
d_path_cntrl    : LUT_data <= 16'h0a06; //Reg 5 Digital Audio Path Control 


power_on            : LUT_data <= 16'h0c00; //Reg 6 Power Down Control 

set_format      : LUT_data <= 16'h0e0e; //Reg 7 Digital Audio Interface Format

sample_cntrl    : LUT_data <= 16'h1000; // Reg 8 Sampling Control
```

It if matters the mic that I am using is a standard aux cord lapel mic.

I have exhausted my debugging options at this point and I am looking for guidance as to why I am not getting an input adcdat signal on my logic analyzer screen.

Any guidance is much appreciated.